# java.net.URI().getPath() return null while the string contains colon?

Tags: java

To be precise, consider the following string example:

```
String str = ":Royal%2Bweddings%3A%2Bceremony%2BThe%2Bsymbolism";
java.net.URI(str).getPath();
```

Here because the `str` contains a `:` colon the `URI().getPath()` returns null but if I remove the colon the return value is as I expect it to be.

So how do I get the `URI().getPath()` to not filter the colon and leave it as it is?

Comment: URI().getPath() `Returns the decoded path component of this URI.`. If no valid path can be decoded  then you will get a null value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to 'escape' from the colon character as follows (using [URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html), as suggested by [Scary Wombat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310289/scary-wombat)):

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MyClass {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try { 
        String str = "https://www.jdoodle.com/online-ja:va-compiler"; 
        String escapedStr = URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(escapedStr);
        String uriPath = new java.net.URI(escapedStr).getPath();
        System.out.println(uriPath);

    } catch (URISyntaxException |  UnsupportedEncodingException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); // just for the sake of this example, this should be logged properly
    }
}
```

}

And the output is:

```
https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jdoodle.com%2Fonline-ja%3Ava-compiler // note the UTF-8 representation for potentially problematic characters
https://www.jdoodle.com/online-ja:va-compiler
```

Originally suggested approach is to use the concept of substring replacement as escaping from problematic characters (depending on your code's business logic) - note this is a general case approach and not suited for URI handling:

```
public class Escaping {

private static final String COLON = ":";
private static final String ESCAPE_COLON = ".colon.";

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String str = "This is my : String : with colons"; 
    String escapedStr = str.replaceAll(COLON,ESCAPE_COLON);
    System.out.println(escapedStr);
    // perfrom whatever action you need with the 'problematic' colon characters
    // ...
    // ...
    System.out.println(escapedStr.replaceAll(ESCAPE_COLON,COLON));
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
This is my .colon. String .colon. with colons
This is my : String : with:
```

References:

- [ASCII Encoding Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)
- [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html)
- [Percent Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

Comment: although your answer worked, but what if my `str` contained `.colon.` then that would be a flaw, right?

Comment: `.colon.` was arbitrarily selected for this example. You may replace it with whatever from you might wish.  `..colon..` could serve just as well.
If my answer was helpful - please consider up-voting or selecting it as your question's answer. Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, a few things about your code. It doesn't compile because you need to use `new` to create a new object:

```
String str = ":Royal%2Bweddings%3A%2Bceremony%2BThe%2Bsymbolism";
new java.net.URI(str).getPath();
```

That code doesn't return `null` - instead it throws a descriptive exception:

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected scheme name at index 0: :Royal%2Bweddings%3A%2Bceremony%2BThe%2Bsymbolism
```

The URI constructor takes a full URI, and a colon has a special meaning - but it needs to be prefixed with a protocol name like `http:` or `file:`.

If you want to use these special characters inside a path, you need to URL-encode the path - that is normal practice for including special characters in a URL or URI:

```
String str = ":Royal%2Bweddings%3A%2Bceremony%2BThe%2Bsymbolism";
str = URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8"); // <---- URL encoding
System.out.println(new java.net.URI(str).getPath());
```

You don't need to come up with your own encoding scheme with your own replacements - URL is the standard. And you don't need to decode either, that is handled automatically by `getPath()`.

However in your case, your path is already partially url-encoded - and it already contains a colon: `Royal+weddings:+ceremony+The+symbolism`.

You need URL-encode the whole path in one go:

```
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(":Royal+weddings:+ceremony+The+symbolism", "UTF-8");
```

Then you're settled.